# Jquery and popper.js not working when I integrated it into angular

Tags: jquery, angular, popper.js

I want to integrate jquery and popper.js in my angular project I installed both and add to packages.json as well as in angular.json but it doesn't work

packages.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  }
```

angular.json:

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: The AngularJS tag is only for that framework (up to version 1.9). Please read the excerpt that shows as you are typing the tags.

Answer (score 0):

First did you do it manually or by npm ?
Second did you restart the server after installing ?

Comment: I did using npm and yes, I restart server after installing

Comment: This would have made a good comment, but it does not make a satisfactory answer. Please wait until you have enough rep to comment. Using answers merely prolongs that eventuality, as people downvote answers that should be comments.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I don't see where the problem is so I add the scripts in index.html now it works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```